# Adding items into n column grids using flex

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flexbox, react-native-stylesheet

I am trying to create a list of items which looks similar to the below image.

Currently I am creating a RowComponent and including ItemContainer component inside to create the mentioned effect.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});

const RowComponent = () => {
  const { containerStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <ItemContainer />
      <ItemContainer />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Main screen view

```
<View style={containerStyle}>
  <RowComponent />
  <RowComponent />
</View>
```

I find this method very inefficient therefore I hope to know how I can create this effect by just duplicating the ItemContainer to create the mentioned effect.

eg:

```
<View style={containerStyle}>
  <ItemContainer />
  <ItemContainer />
  <ItemContainer />
  <ItemContainer />
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can create this effect by just duplicating the ItemContainer to
>   create the mentioned effect.

You can set `flexWrap` property to `wrap` in your `containerStyle`. Like this:

```
  containerStyle: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap:"wrap"
  },
```

And now without `RowComponent` you can achieve the same layout.

---

```
<View style={styles.containerStyle}>

    <View style={styles.itemContainer} />
    <View style={styles.itemContainer} />
    <View style={styles.itemContainer} />
    <View style={styles.itemContainer} />
    <View style={styles.itemContainer} />

</View>
```

Style:

```
  containerStyle: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap:"wrap"
  },
  itemContainer: {
    width:"45%",
    height:80,
    marginRight:"5%",
    marginBottom:10,
    backgroundColor:"red"
  }
```

[image]